# Connect Macbook Pro to Dell U2311H - HDMI to DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook, dvi

I tried to connect my Macbook Pro (purchased 2015) with a Dell U2311H monitor using an HDMI cable with a [Rankie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010SDZZ80) adapter between the HDMI port on the Macbook and the DisplayPort on the monitor, but the monitor says no signal is detected, and the Macbook doesn't show the Dell in Display preferences.

Any idea what might be going on?  I've verified that the monitor works when I connect directly using my Macbook's HDMI port to the monitor's DVI-D port.

Comment: You need an active HDMI source to DisplayPort sink adapter/cable, not a passive DisplayPort(++) source to HDMI sink one.

Comment: @TomYan - Thanks. I think that answers my question.